# Sphinx - Duplicated results when searching

Tags: php, full-text-search, sphinx

There's a way to avoid that when searching in Sphinx, there are results with id duplicated because are in both indexes (main and delta)? I know that I can resolve this running a merge of both indexes, but I want to know if there is another way to avoid the merge because could be expensive for the server run it every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Just run your query against the both indexes at once by making a distributed index with them as locals or agents or just using a comma in your search query, e.g.:

```
mysql> select * from idx_min;
+------+--------------------------------------------------------------+------+
| id   | doc                                                          | a    |
+------+--------------------------------------------------------------+------+
|    1 | dog cat parrot juice apple mandarine juice juice apple juice |  123 |
|    2 | dog cat juice apple apple juice                              |  123 |
+------+--------------------------------------------------------------+------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from idx_min2;
+------+--------------------------------------------------------------+------+
| id   | doc                                                          | a    |
+------+--------------------------------------------------------------+------+
|    1 | dog cat parrot juice apple mandarine juice juice apple juice |  123 |
|    2 | dog cat juice apple apple juice                              |  123 |
+------+--------------------------------------------------------------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I.e. we can see that the both indexes have docs with ids 1 and 2. But:

```
mysql> select * from idx_min, idx_min2;
+------+--------------------------------------------------------------+------+
| id   | doc                                                          | a    |
+------+--------------------------------------------------------------+------+
|    1 | dog cat parrot juice apple mandarine juice juice apple juice |  123 |
|    2 | dog cat juice apple apple juice                              |  123 |
+------+--------------------------------------------------------------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

gives us the documents with duplicates removed.

2) To make the way of de-duplication more controlled you can use kill-lists. Kill-list is a list of IDs assigned to an index which says that these ids should be removed from any preceding indexes. Depending on the version you're using (Sphinx 2 / Manticore / Sphinx 3) the commands to define a kill-list and the behaviour may vary.

Comment: I'm already using the first solution, but If I search some content that is in the first index and also in the second index (with some changes) I received the result. E.g if in your example the doc column of the first row contains "hello world" and I search for that word, I receive that result, even if the same row is inside the second index with different value.

Comment: Instead I'm seeing the second solution, and maybe is what I'm searching

Comment: With Kill-list it works how expected, thanks a lot :)